# MySql select if date is NOT more than 15 min ago

Tags: php, mysql, sql, time

I am trying to make a login system that logs you out after 15 minutes of inactivity. Here is my current code for fetching the data:

```
$itemResult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `logins` WHERE token = '$token' AND logged_date xxxxx");
```

This is where I am stuck. The date is formatted like this: `yy/mm/dd h:m`

I need to select everything with the correct token that is no more than 15 minutes old. How do I do that?

Comment: check this link:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4838120/select-from-mysql-table-between-datetime-x-min-ago-and-datetime-x-min-ago

Comment: Why use a database for this? Store the date/time of the last activity in a session variable, update it every time the user does something and use that to track inactivity.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18726873/where-datetime-older-than-15-minutes

Comment: @HoboSapiens If user close the browser the session will be destroy. in this case, we need to 15min for editing.

Comment: @anantkumarsingh You didn't want to flag it as a dupe of one of those?

Comment: @stack So you want to leave a session logged in after the browser closes? Someone reopening that browser within the time window could potentially reopen the session and do, well, whatever...

Comment: i don't understand what you said?

Comment: @HoboSapiens what ? can I define a session based on time ? *(15 min alive)*  , I want when user closes the browser, still session be alive (not destroys until 15min be over). is it possible ?

Comment: @stack What you suggest is possible, but nobody with a serious eye on security would do it.

Comment: @HoboSapiens can you explain me more your first comment ? **Why use a database for this?**

Comment: @HoboSapiens when I write a comment on stackoverflow, there is a time after my comment (for my comment), and I can edit my comment just for 5 min, Now I want to know, Is it on session or database ?

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation:

Because you are using a `varchar` column type you need to convert them to the same type, either change your database to store the date as a date (typically best practice anyways) or use `str_to_date()` to convert your string to a date before comparing.

Then we use the `NOW()` function to get the current datetime, subtract an interval of 15 minutes from the value of `NOW()` and compare it to the `logged_date` column

Or you could use [Date_format()](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp) to convert the `now - 15min` date to a string

`date_format(DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 15 MINUTE), '%y/%m/%d %h:%i')` and then compare your varchar to that

### Query:

```
SELECT *
FROM `logins`
WHERE token = '$token'
      AND 
      str_to_date(logged_date, '%y/%m/%d %h:%i') >= DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 15 MINUTE)
```

Comment: Does not seem to work. Even though the row is more than 15 minutes old, it is still accepted by the query as a valid result.

Comment: Is the logged_date a datetime column type or varchar or what?

Comment: Either change the column type to a date type or use the edit I posted

Comment: See if the changes I made to my post help you @user2372837

Comment: I have changed it to a DATETIME value in my database, but the old code still dosent work?